# How do I calculate the confidence interval for tau2 in R, using the Paule-Mandel estimator and Q-Profile confidence intervals?

Tags: r, meta-analysis

I am currently completing a meta-analysis of raw mean scores. I have used the R function metamean to complete this, and chose the Paule-Mandel estimator for tau-squared as I have a small number of studies and large tau-squared value.

I am now trying to calculate Q-profile confidence intervals for tau-squared, however any R code I find to calculate confidence intervals does not seem to work; and I get the below error:

> Confint(SMD)
>
> Error in vcov.default(object) : 
>     object does not have variance-covariance matrix

I believe this error is due to my meta-analysis being completed with either escalc or metamean. Is there anyway of being able to compute the confidence intervals of tau-squared?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You might do better to ask on the R meta-analysis mailing list https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis// where the author of the package which you are using (but did not name) often posts.